# How to define handler with and without slash in app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to have the same handler for my urls with and without slash at the end:

```
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/someVariable
http://mysite.appspot.com/something/something-else/someVariable/
```

How should I define the same in app.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
/something/something-else/someVariable/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in `app.yaml`, I'd do it in your handler script in the `WSGIApplication`, using the technique systempuntoout shows.